# Back button on the bottom/footer

Tags: ios, iphone

When designing an IOS app, can I put "Back" button feature at the footer?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can put it there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything in the guidelines that forbids this, however your potential users are used to the back button being on the top left corner, so unless you have a really good reason for placing the back button on the bottom, and you're sure that your users will be OK with it, I would recommend against it.

Comment: This is an answer I agree with.